# Convert Rcpp Armadillo matrix to double*

Tags: rcpp, armadillo

In RcppArmadillo, I need to know how I can convert `arma::mat` to c-style array `double *` for use in other functions.

When I run the following functions, the computer crashes:

R part:

```
      nn3 <- function(x){
         results=.Call("KNNCV", PACKAGE = "KODAMA", x)
         results
      }
```

C++ part:

```
     double  KNNCV(arma::mat x) {
        double *cvpred = x.memptr();
        return cvpred[1];
     }
```

and at the end, I try:

```
     nn3(as.matrix(iris[,-5]))
```

Can you help me to find the errors, please?

Answer (score 8):

First, there is no such such thing as *vector stored in a `double*`*. You can cast to a C-style pointer to double; but without length information that does not buy you much.

By convention, most similar C++ classes give you a `.begin()` iterator to the beginning of the memory block (which Armadillo happens to guarantee to be contiguous, just like `std::vector`) so you can try that.

Other than that the (very fine indeed) [Armadillo documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) tells you about [memptr()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#memptr) which is probably what you want here.  Straight copy from the example there:

```
      mat A = randu<mat>(5,5);
const mat B = randu<mat>(5,5);

      double* A_mem = A.memptr();
const double* B_mem = B.memptr();
```

Comment: What if I wanted to create an actual double array by `double dArr[vecSize] = armaVec` where `armaVec` is  of `arma::vec` type? The syntax here doesn't seem to be valid as I just tried in IDE; but I am thinking if there's something to this effect.  I can then reference it `&dArr`.