# Rcpp & main/optim.c - How to translate `void *ex` after passing the variable through `nmmin()`?

Tags: c++, r, optimization, rcpp

**Main question:** How to format a complex struct in Rcpp that will be accepted by optim.c? and how will this struct be modified when returned to the defined optimfn function?

**Background:** I'm writing an EM algorithm in Rcpp that will be used in a beta mixture model. I am trying to use a simple nelder mead numerical optimization approach through the R API (nmmin), however I am having a hard time passing the variable list through. I'm very very new to C++/Rcpp.

**Information:**

eout countains:

- zprobs: a matrix (double[45203x5]).  (the number of col and rows will vary).
- parmlist: a list which contains lists avec, mvec, and svec (each list of 5 doubles). (the length will vary).
- xi: a list of doubles of length 45203. (the length will vary).
- denom: a list of doubles of length 45203. (the length will vary).

To pass my variables through to `nmmin`, I've tried to convert it to a struct format by first converting the NumericMatrix and NumericVector into `double *var`, ([but I then learned these are not real](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167678/convert-rcpp-armadillo-matrix-to-double/37168659#37168659) (edit: that these do not hold vectors)), followed by creating an object with my defined struct with these items. The current method is able to compile, but I am not sure what `*ex` looks like when it enters the `enlikeB` function. I also tried to convert the `Rcpp::List` items to `std::vectors`, in case these were possible to pass through.

**Where I am currently:**

```
#include <RcppCommon.h>

typedef struct{
  double *xi;
  int xil;
  int zrows;
  int zcols;
  double *zdata;
  double *denom;
  int denoml;
}Ething;

#include <Rcpp.h>

//HELPER FUNCTIONS HERE:
//


// Defining the optimfn function:
typedef double optimfn(int n, double *par, void *ex);

double elnlikeB(int n, double *par, void *ex) {
 
   Rcpp::Rcout << "entering elnlikeB\n";
   Rcpp::Rcout << "The value of ex: " << ex << "\n";

   Ething *et = (Ething *) ex;
   Rcpp::Rcout << "The value of et : " << et << "\n";

   Rcpp::Rcout << "making z\n";
   int zrows = et ->zrows;
   int zcols = et ->zcols;
   double *z = et ->zdata;
   Rcpp::NumericMatrix Zprobsmat;
   int count = 0;
   for(int x = 0; x < zcols; x++) {
     for(int y = 0; y < zrows; y++) {
       Zprobsmat(y, x) = z[count]; //row, column
       count = count +1;
     }
   }
   Rcpp::Rcout << "The value of zprob : " << Zprobsmat << "\n";
   
   Rcpp::Rcout << "making xi\n";
   int xil = et -> xil;
   double *xid = et -> xi;
   Rcpp::NumericVector xi;
   for(int nn = 0; nn < xil; nn++){
     xi[nn] = xid[nn];
   } 
   Rcpp::Rcout << "The value of xi : " << xi << "\n";
   
   Rcpp::Rcout << "making denom\n";
   int denoml = et ->denoml;
   double *denomd =  et -> denom; 
   Rcpp::NumericVector denom;
   for(int nn = 0; nn < denoml; nn++){
     denom[nn] = denomd[nn];
   } 
   Rcpp::Rcout << "The value of denom: " << denom << "\n";
   
   Rcpp::Rcout << "making myguess\n";
   Rcpp::NumericVector myguess;
   for(int nn = 0; nn < n; nn++){
    myguess[nn] = par[nn];
   } 
   Rcpp::Rcout << "The value of myguess: " << myguess << "\n";
   
   //This section works is the vectors and matrix are correct//
   Rcpp::Rcout << "calculating\n";
   int nnew = xi.size();
   int nmixt = Zprobsmat.ncol();
   int gsize = myguess.size();
   
   Rcpp::NumericVector avec(nmixt);
   avec[Rcpp::Range(0, (nmixt - 2))] = invmlogitc(myguess[Rcpp::Range(0, (nmixt - 2))]);
   avec[(nmixt-1)] = (1 - rcpp_sum(avec));
   Rcpp::NumericVector mvec(nmixt);
   Rcpp::NumericVector svec(nmixt);
      
   mvec = mutransform(myguess[Rcpp::Range((nmixt-1), (((nmixt-1)*2)))]);
   svec = stransform(myguess[Rcpp::Range((((nmixt-1)*2)+1), (gsize-1))]);
   
   Rcpp::NumericMatrix loglikemat( nnew, nmixt );
   Rcpp::NumericMatrix lnfr( nnew, nmixt );
   double sum = 0;
   
   for(int i = 0; i < nmixt; i++){
     double a = log(avec[i]);
     double m = mvec[i];
     double s = svec[i];
     Rcpp::NumericVector ab = alphabetacalc(m, s);
     for( int z = 0;  z < nnew; z++){
         lnfr(z,i) = (R::dbeta( xi[z], ab[0], ab[1], true));
       
         double left = (Zprobsmat(z,i)/denom[z]);
         double right = (a + lnfr(z,i));
         loglikemat(z, i) = (left*right);
         sum += loglikemat(z, i);
     }
   }
   sum = (-sum);
   Rprintf("sum: %d \n", sum);
   return(sum);
 }

optimfn elnlikeB;
 
//More helpers
 extern "C" {
   void nmmin(int n, double *xin, double *x, double *Fmin, optimfn fn,
              int *fail, double abstol, double intol, void *ex,
              double alpha, double beta, double gamma, int trace,
              int *fncount, int maxit);
 }
 
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List optim_test(Rcpp::List eout){
   Rcpp::Rcout << "starting\n";
   Rcpp::Rcout << "making avec, mvec, svec\n"; 
   Rcpp::List parmlist = eout["parm.list"];
   Rcpp::NumericVector avec = parmlist["avec"];
   Rcpp::NumericVector mvec = parmlist["mvec"];
   Rcpp::NumericVector svec = parmlist["svec"];
   Rcpp::Rcout << "making zprob and xi \n"; 
   Rcpp::NumericMatrix Zprobsmat = eout["zprob"];
   Rcpp::NumericVector xi = eout["xi"];
   int xil = xi.size();
   Rcpp::NumericVector denom = eout["denom"];
   int denoml = denom.size();
   double nmixt = avec.size();
   Rcpp::NumericVector mas = mlogitc(avec, nmixt);
   Rcpp::Rcout << "making guess\n"; 
   int gl = ((nmixt-1) + nmixt + nmixt);
   Rcpp::NumericVector guess(gl);
   guess[Rcpp::Range(0, (nmixt-2))] = mas;
   guess[Rcpp::Range((nmixt-1), ((nmixt-1)*2))] = min(mvec);
   guess[Rcpp::Range((((nmixt-1)*2)+1), (gl-1))] = sin(svec);
   
   Rcpp::Rcout << "making zdata\n"; 
   
   int tl = (xil*nmixt);
   Rcpp::NumericVector zdata(tl);
   int count = 0;
   for(int x = 0; x < nmixt; x++) {
     for(int y = 0; y < xil; y++) {
       zdata[count] = Zprobsmat(y, x); //row, column
       count = count +1;
     }
   }

   int zrows = xil;
   int zcols = nmixt;
   
   Rcpp::Rcout << "making et\n"; 
   
   Rcpp::List et =  Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("xi") = xi, Rcpp::Named("xil") = xil, 
                                                     Rcpp::Named("zrows") = zrows, 
Rcpp::Named("zcols") = zcols,
                                                       Rcpp::Named("zdata") = zdata, Rcpp::Named("denom") = denom,
                                                       Rcpp::Named("denoml") =denoml);
    

   Rcpp::Rcout << "making guess vec\n";
   double vec[gl];
   for(int nn = 0; nn < gl; nn++){
     vec[nn] = guess[nn];
   } 

   double opar[gl];
   double Fmin = 0.0;
   int fail = 0;
   double abstol = 1.0e-8;
   double intol = 1.0e-8;
   double alpha = 1.0;
   double beta = 0.5;
   double gamma = 2.0;
   int trace =0;
   int fncount = 0;
   int maxit = 500;
   Rcpp::Rcout << "Attempting nmmin\n";
  
   nmmin(gl, vec, opar, &Fmin, 
        elnlikeB, &fail, abstol, intol, &et, alpha, beta, 
        gamma, trace, &fncount, maxit);


   Rcpp::List res = Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::_["Fmin"] = Fmin, Rcpp::_["fail"]=fail);
   return(res);`
 }
```

Comment: "they are not real" - that answer only explains the difference between a pointer and an array. A pointer is not an array, but a pointer can point to first element of an array, and thats what `nmmin` seems to expect

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow -- and to Rcpp and C++!  That is *a lot* at once and I would recommend you at least casually poke at some of the existing optimisation packages using R, C++, Rcpp, ....  I have example repos for working with NLopt (via the `nloptr` package) with Rcpp and RcppArmadillo example packages. Then there is RcppEnsmallen.  And more.  You are hitting some fundamental questions here and there are really no shortcuts so my recommendation is to give with trusted and used packages _and their examples_ first.

Comment: @EricPostpischil [optim.c](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/appl/optim.c#L52) is in C?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I've probably been a little too narrow with my search. I've been focused on [oce](https://github.com/dankelley/oce/blob/cd7f98d968a703710de21cee9ad94b1d3cf0772b/src/geod.cpp#L223), [forecast](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/14346c64163312127ebd4ce6a25890d5208e8a17/src/etsTargetFunctionWrapper.cpp#L166), and [SharedHT2](https://github.com/cran/SharedHT2/blob/d841f0822bfd21cf4ea77ac039276f3e0f200690/src/Fit_F.c#L15). Will have a look at nloptr now!

Comment: The question is not about C. One C file in a project does not justify the C tag by itself.

Comment: You probably want `RcppNLoptExample` (at GitHub under my handle, and on CRAN) and `RcppArmadilloNLoptExample` (possibly only at GitHub under my handle) rather than the 'raw' `nloptr`.  And consider `RcppEnsmallen` too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Instead of `typedef struct`, I defined a class:

```
class Ething {
public:
  double *xi;
  int xil;
  int zrows;
  int zcols;
  double *zdata;
  double *denom;
  int denoml;
  
  Ething(double *xi, int xil, int zrows, int zcols, double *zdata, double *denom, int denoml) : xi(xi), xil(xil), zrows(zrows), zcols(zcols), zdata(zdata), denom(denom), denoml(denoml) {}
};
```

After converting my data into the correct format, I was able to make the `void *ex` object equal to:

```
Ething et(xid, xil, zrows, zcols, zdata, denomd, denoml);
```

This allows you to surpass setting the memory/size when creating the object and passes the object as formatted in an easy-to-interpret manner. The full code will be available on github under `mgaynor1/nQuack` in a few months.

Comment: Good!  That is one way.  Now that you have a class, you can also access it / pass it around via `Rcpp::XPtr` wrapping R's external pointer interface.  (This is not exactly day one material.)  The other way would have been casting to `void*` which is more of older-school C approach with less 'typed' and compile-time control.  Keep at it!  The rcpp-devel is also there.